# New Game+ in Pocket League Story

Tags: pocket-league-story

I'm a huge Kairosoft fan, and I've played through most of their games multiple times with the new game plus feature, transferring something (item, research) from the previous save.

I didn't find this option in Pocket League Story, has anyone succeeded in transferring anything from the old game? If this isn't possible, the replayability suffers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first I was confused as well, but don't worry, it's there. After your total points are calculated, many things are saved to the base new game template. Whenever you start a new game, the game will use the new setup. Every time you hit the end of March in year 8 this happens.

Available players (and their levels and stats) are saved. Coach levels and learned formations are saved. All upgrades except for stadium and field upgrades are saved. Fan Activity levels are saved. Previously owned players start at 50% interest. Sponsor interest is saved (previously signed sponsors start at 100%, but points still need to be spent to resign). Facility placement is saved.

When you start a new game, you will start with the initial players and coach, as well as starting money and available matches. You will have to reassemble your team, which takes time. However, you instantly benefit from the upgraded facilities from your last play.

From what I hear, it takes about 3+ play-throughs to unlock everything, so have fun!